# How to preview files inside an app component using react-native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, preview

I'm trying to preview files inside my component. Currently I'm using [react-native-file-viewer](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer), which can't open the files inside the component and takes up the whole screen. Is there any way to achieve this in react-native?

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
  <Grid>
    <Col size={30}>
      ...
    </Col>
    <Col size={70} style={{ backgroundColor: '#00CE9F'}}>
      //Preview should go here
    </Col>
  </Grid>
</SafeAreaView>
```

The preview should be displayed on the right side.
[image: Screenshot]
This is the current preview:
[image: Current Preview]

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of how it looks currently?

Comment: @Rajan Added screenshots to my question

Comment: Just a question are you want to show only image or any file?

Comment: @Rajan I want to open any file, especially Office-Documents, PDFs, videos and images.